# A safer way to reference a private member variable in public member function call?

Tags: c++, class, stdvector

I want to use a single function to interact with multiple private member variables. I've come up with:

```
class Some_Vectors {

public:
  int is_value_in_vector(string vector_name, int value);
  void append_value_to_vector(string vector_name, int value)

private:
  vector<int> A;
  vector<int> B;

};


// returns value's index if it's there, -1 if not
int Some_Vectors::is_value_in_vector(string vector_name, int value) {

  vector<int> *selected_vector;

  if (vector_name == "A") {selected_vector = &A;}
  else if (vector_name == "B") {selected_vector = &B;}

  for (int i = 0; i < selected_vector->size(); i++){
    if (selected_vector[0][i] == value){
      return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

It works, but I feels unsafe/brittle to compare strings like that. Is there a way to specifically reference a private variable in the function call?

Edited to be a (hopefully) less subjective ask. I ended up using RichardCritten's suggestion of multiple public functions that call a single private function.

Comment: What is the usage scenario for your `Some_Vectors` type? Why not just use an `unordered_map<string,vector<T>>`?

Comment: Create 2 public functions with meaningful names (to the user).  Pass the appropriate vector by const reference to a private helper function that does the work.

Comment: @Dai - This is just a simplified bit from a larger class I'm working on. I will read up on unordered_map, though. Thank you.

Comment: @RichardCritten That makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: Without a specification what what you mean by "best" (or, more generally, criteria by which you might decide that one approach is "better" than another) any answers to this question are opinion-based.     Neither "better" nor "best" are absolute concepts - if my criterion for "best" differs from yours, then we will naturally articulate different solutions.   Voting to close accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `unordered_map` to achieve your requirements as below.

1. Declare the `unordered_map` as below.

   ```
   unordered_map<string, vector<int>> umap;
   ```
2. Insert the values to map by using [] operator.

   ```
   umap["A"] = {10,20}; 
   umap["B"] = {30,40};
   ```
3. Search the key value in the `unordered_map` as below using find function.

   ```
   string vector_name = "A";

   vector_name = "A";


   auto it = umap.find(vector_name);
   if (it == umap.end())
       return -1;
   ```
4. Once you find the `key,value` pair in the map search the particular `int` in the `vector` as below.

   ```
   std::vector<int>::iterator iter = std::find(it->second.begin(), it->second.end(), 20);
   ```
5. if `iter` is not pointing the `vector` end then return the exact position of the `int` in the `vector` as below.

   ```
   if ( iter !=  it->second.end())
       return std::distance(it->second.begin(),iter);
   else
       return -1;
   ```

Your complete sample code may look like below.

```
int main() 
{ 

    unordered_map<string, vector<int>> umap; 

    // inserting values by using [] operator 
    umap["A"] = {10,20}; 
    umap["B"] = {30,40}; 


    string vector_name = "A"; 

    vector_name = "A"; 


    auto it = umap.find(vector_name);
    if (it == umap.end())
    return -1;

    std::vector<int>::iterator iter = std::find(it->second.begin(), it->second.end(), 20);

    if ( iter !=  it->second.end())
     return std::distance(it->second.begin(),iter);
    else
    return -1;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have to disagree with the other answers that suggest maps or any kind of solutions involving strings.

Using strings to identify things **in code** is very fragile. Some major disadvantages are: no autocomplete, no compile-time checks. There are situations where you don't have a better alternative (e.g. you don't know the identifiers at compile time), but this is not one of them.

One solution is to give meaningful names to the functions. Since you provided a toy example I will use `A` and `B` but in real life they should be meaningful names:

```
class X
{
    public:
    auto foo_a(int value) { return foo(A, value); }
    auto foo_b(int value) { return foo(B, value); }

private:
    int foo(std::vector<int>& v, int value) { return 24; }

    std::vector<int> A;
    std::vector<int> B;
};
```

If you want one function with a parameter to select the vector, you should select the vector with an enum. This way you have autocomplete and **compile-time** safety (you can't pass an invalid selector - like you could with a string - unless you bend backwards):

```
class Y
{
public:
    enum class Selector { A, B };

    auto foo(Selector selector, int value) { return foo(getVector(selector), value); }

private:
    std::vector<int>& getVector(Selector selector)
    {
        switch (selector)
        {
            case Selector::A:
                return A;
            case Selector::B:
                return B;
        }
    }

    int foo(std::vector<int>& v, int value) { return 24; }

    std::vector<int> A;
    std::vector<int> B;
};
```

```
Y y{};

y.foo(Y::Selector::A, 11);
y.foo(Y::Selector::B, 1024);
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you have access to C++17 or later versions of compilers the most modern and preferable way of optional return would be using **[`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional)**.

Regarding your question, as @Dai mentioned in the comments, the best way would be(IMHO also) to use

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector</*type*/>>
```

as the member variable and you can do as follows. [See Live here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zB44g2ugwMADXQPb)

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>

using uMapType = std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<int>>;
class MyClass
{
private:
   uMapType _vecMap;
public:
  explicit MyClass(const uMapType& vecMap): _vecMap(std::move(vecMap)) {}

  int getValue(const std::string &vector_name, const int value)const
  {
     // std::unordered_map::find the key(vector name)
     auto getVec = _vecMap.find(vector_name);
     if(getVec != _vecMap.cend())   // if iterator not pointing to map's end
     {
        const std::vector<int> &selected_vector = getVec->second;
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < selected_vector.size(); ++i)
           if (selected_vector[i] == value)
              return i;
     }
     return -1; 
  }
};


int main()
{
    MyClass obj(
    {
        {"A", {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}},
        {"B", {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}
    });

    std::cout << obj.getValue("A", 3) << std::endl; // output: 2
    std::cout << obj.getValue("B", 5) << std::endl; // output: 5
    std::cout << obj.getValue("C", 3) << std::endl; // output: -1
    std::cout << obj.getValue("A", 0) << std::endl; // output: -1
    return 0;
}
```

---

The `std::optional` sample solution will look like this.

```
#include <optional>

using uMapType = std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<int>>;
class MyClass
{
private:
   uMapType _vecMap;
public:
  explicit MyClass(const uMapType& vecMap): _vecMap(std::move(vecMap)) {}

  std::optional<int> getValue(const std::string &vector_name, const int value)const
  {
      if(auto getVec = _vecMap.find(vector_name); getVec != _vecMap.cend())
      {
          for (std::size_t i = 0; i < getVec->second.size(); ++i)
            if (getVec->second[i] == value)
                return i;
      }
      return std::nullopt;
  }
};
```